# Best ways to store private keys on a client?

Tags: privacy, storage, public-key

I am currently writing a program that sends an encrypted file to the client, and I don't want the user to be able to access the file directly (though the client program will operate on it).
Since the client will be written in Java, which is prone to reverse engineering methods like decompilers as well as things like javaagent, ASM, and reflection, I got stuck on how I would be able to send the private key safely to the client application.

Currently, I have two ideas:

1. Include the private key with the jar file
2. Send the private key over HTTPS after the client runs and cache it in memory

However, with case 1 I am unsure how I would include the key in a jar file if I don't want the user to be able to access it; and with case 2 I am worried about the user intercepting HTTP packets.

What should I do to keep the data as secure as possible?

Thanks

Comment: the answer from the user named "nobody" is a good one. if you really want to keep the data as secure as possible, don't sent it to the client. for example, let's say the client is analyzing the data and drawing a chart. if you move the analysis and drawing to the server (and send the client an image), then the client won't ever have the raw data. while this is most likely not the answer you're looking for, there's a trade-off here.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, the problem you are trying to solve is the same as DRM. It is practically impossible to securely store secrets client side (at least without specialized hardware), since the user has unlimited access to the client and can modify and inspect it at will.

> Include the private key with the jar file

As you say, the user can easily reverse engineer and recover the private key. Obfuscating the key may make it harder to retrieve the key, but any decent determined reverse-engineer will eventually be able to recover it.

> Send the private key over HTTPS after the client runs and cache it in memory
>
> I am worried about the user intercepting HTTP packets.

To solve this specific problem, you could use certificate pinning to prevent the user from simply using some sort of TLS inspection proxy to intercept and inspect the packets. However, a reverse engineer could remove the restriction from your application. Or they could just dump the memory and retrieve the key from there.

If you are trying to prevent casual users from being able to extract the key, hardcoding the key along with some obfuscation should be sufficient. However, if you want to prevent an experienced reverse engineer from extracting the key, you are out of luck.